# Coaxial CATV to power line adapter

Tags: electrical, television, coaxial-cable, catv

When I renovated my apartment and redid my electrical wiring, I missed the chance to set up network and tv cable too. While internet is fortunately solved by Wi-Fi, I am not so lucky about TV.

The signal is delivered by the provider via coaxial cables. I noticed there are devices on the market that can pass internet signal over power lines and wondered if there is something similar for TV signal? My searches returned nothing. If this is not possible, is there any other way to pass TV signal without a lot of new wires around the house?

Comment: There are solutions for wireless transmission of video from a computer to monitor, but none that I'm aware of for CATV. You may be stuck with "creative" wiring solutions or moving the TV...

Comment: That’s hard to do. Cable TV is a staggering amount of bandwidth.  It’s every channel at once, in HD.  It’s literally the entire radio spectrum, on a cable.  To do that wirelessly, you’d need ... the entire radio spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really such a product since power cables are unable to carry the bandwidth needed for broadband signals such as CATV.  The best you might be able to do is a remote video sharing device that is hooked to the CATV tuner.  These devices take HDMI from your video source, transmit it over WiFi, and then turn it back into HDMI at the receiver.

This article offers some options:

[HDMI over WiFi](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/the-best-wireless-hdmi-video-transmitter/)

To quote a section:

> The Iogear GW3DHDKIT Wireless HDMI Digital Kit is the best HDMI
> transmitter for most people. Using WHDI, it delivers the best image
> from the lengthiest distances, has two HDMI inputs, and can be powered
> via an included AC adapter or your TV’s USB 3.0 connection (cables not
> included). It’s also the least expensive dual HDMI unit we tested.

I know nothing about this particular unit but it or something like it may do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for sending catv wireless but wil involve costs greater than your TV setup
In short: Catv decoder + IR extender + wireless video/audio transmiter+receiver..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/150810)